# Big R frame conversion - connection error Biginsights v4

Tags: r, jdbc, biginsights

I am trying to proceed with the bluemix tutorial " analyzing big data with R".  When connecting to BigSQL,I am getting a generic error message (" Error: BigR[bigr.connect]: Connection could not be established. Verify connection parameters"), however the when checking connection ("is.bigR.connected") it returns true.

When proceeding with the tutorial, when trying to execute a bigR frame conversion I am getting a series of error messages, partly copied here (" Error: BigR[.bigr.jdbc.query.helper]: Error code : 15, SQLState : 58004
Caused by : The stack trace :java.sql.SQLException  at com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.jdbc.BigSQLStatement.executeQuery(BigSQLStatement.java:91)").

I am not sure if they could be related to the connection-issue mentioned above, but I am unable to proceed.

I have searched the internet for solutions, but without results (I am very new to Hadoop/SQL/bigR). Hoping for some feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After thorough investigation I adjusted the bigr.connect statement (especially double checked the password parameter as well as truststore path).  Error messages dissapeared.